# Configure Pyright to use Ruff as a linter

Tags: python, linter, language-server-protocol, pyright, python-language-server

I use Zed editor with Pyright and it works like a charm. However I want to use Ruff linter with Pyright but I don't find any documentation about how to achieve this for Zed editor. Do I have to specify linter directly in `pyrightconfig.json` and if so how?

I'm a bit lost about langage server and how to specify linting for specific LSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't special an external linter for Pyright.